# Using cordova.plugins.notification.local, Can I make the message text changes dynamically?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I am developing an app using Inetl XDK and the cordova plugin "cordova.plugins.notification.local" to send daily notifications to the user. Everything is fine except one big issue, I want the message title (or message text) to change daily dynamically, however when I use repeating notifications with this statement

```js
      
    var now= new Date(); 
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.update({
         id: 1,
         title: now,
         text: "Some Message",
         firstAt: now,
         every: 'day'
     });
```

I was trying to make the title dynamic with the value of the current date every day, however what happens is that it takes the value of the date with scheduling and remains as such and don't change daily.
I need help on how I make the title or text of a repeating notification variable that changes with every triggering. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a limitation in the plugin. I suggest you contact the plugin author by posting a message on the plugin's issues page and ask them how to do what you're trying to do, or how to modify the plugin to meet your needs.